# Using OCL and UML with Design Patterns

Tags: design-patterns, uml, ocl

Has anyone tried creating UML profiles for design patterns with stereotypes and OCL constraints? I'm trying to create one for the Singleton pattern but not sure how and where to start...

Answer (score 0):

This will be difficult: many times the design patterns require to look at how objects are used, like in the Singleton pattern. But mostly object-use will occur INSIDE methods (for the Singleton, e.g. [absence of] constructor invocations). The method bodies however are usually not modeled in UML.

Comment: UML has pretty much all the apparatus you need to describe behaviour.  Sequence/Activity Diagrams can show interactions.  OCL pre/post conditions can formalise method/activity behaviour.  Whether you /should/ do it is another question entirely... but all the necessary constructs are there.

Answer (score 0):

Obvious question is "why?"

Are you trying to formally describe the patterns?  Or use them as building blocks for an architecture? Something else?

If it's formal description then you probably don't need stereotypes.  Model the structure with standard class diagrams (per the book) and then formalise method behaviour using pre- and post-conditions in OCL.

There are some papers on formalising patterns with OCL (just google).  Another good source is [this book](http://www.irisa.fr/prive/jezequel/DesignPatterns/).  Although Eiffel-based, it formalises all the GoF patterns with pre-and post conditions on methods.  (All source code available at link).

hth.

Answer (score 0):

There are many papers about formalisation of patterns, however most of them lack one thing or another or are too complex to be practical. However if you want to try OCL will help you quite a lot. For example to specify singleton pattern, you only need to get all instances of given class and count them. If you make this to an invariant on a class, you get singleton very easily.